# Splash screen is stretched on orientation change instead of using the other available image file

Tags: android, cordova, orientation, splash-screen

I have two image files that I want to use as splash screens, one for each orientation. My app already correctly loads the appropriate image file depending on the orientation my device has when first opening the application. If I tilt my device while the splash screen is being shown, however, the current image is just stretched to fit the new orientation.

How do I force my app to load the other image file instead? If that is not possible, can I disable the tilting/resizing of the splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

keep your landscape oriented image in **drawable-land-mdpi** folder

Comment: android:screenOrientation="portrait"  add this in <activity> tag in manifest. It will disable the screen rotation

Answer (score -1):

```
you can use predefined method of Activity..

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration cnf) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(cnf);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (cnf.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (cnf.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do I use instead of the "Toast.makeText" part?